# Batch File- Code Not Working Properly?

Tags: batch-file

I'm printing findstr results as a text file and  deleting the files which are printed as a text file, but i am facing some issues !

My code is like:

```
@echo off
findstr /s /m "Trojan" "C:\*.*">>"C:\result.txt" 2>nul 
for %%i in (C:\result.txt) do del %%i
```

But, i am not able to delete the file(s) with the help of the code above, because it's not delteing file(s) which have spaces in their path

Example-

It is deleting "C:\Anything.exe" which has "Trojan" as a string

It is not deleting "C:\Anything xyz.exe" which has "Trojan" as a string

Please Help to optimize my code !!!

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (C:\result.txt) do del "%%i"
```

You need `for /f` to read the file, an empty delimiter list to avoid splitting the line on spaces while reading the file and proper quoting in the `del` command.